# Setting UILabel with attributed string as titleView nav controller results in weird behaviour

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to set the `titleView` of a `UINavigationController` with multiple lines in a `UILabel`.

I need the two lines to be different font sizes but perfectly aligned so I figured I'd use a `attributed string` to do so. Here's my code:

```
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 44)];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.numberOfLines = 2;
label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize: 14.0f];
label.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.5];
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

UIFont *fontSmall = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:11.0];
NSDictionary *attrsDictionarySmall =
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:fontSmall
                            forKey:NSFontAttributeName];

NSAttributedString *attrSmallString =
[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"small text"
                                attributes:attrsDictionarySmall];

UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Medium" size:14.0];
NSDictionary *attrsDictionary =
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:font
                            forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
NSAttributedString *attrString =
[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"$200"
                                attributes:attrsDictionary];

label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@",attrString,attrBTCString];

self.navigationItem.titleView = label;
```

However, this results in the following:

[image]

How do I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSAttributedString` has a `NSString` property which can be used here.

```
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@",attrString.string,attrSmallString.string];
```